# How do I change my data from bytes to strings in this function?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, unicode, twisted

I have some code for networking program. and its

```
def dataReceived(self, data)
    print(f"Received quote: {data}") 
    self.transport.loseConnection()
```

This function is printing

```
Received quote: b'\x00&C:\\Users\\.pycharm2016.3\\config\x00&C:\\users\\pych‌​arm\\system\x00\x03-‌​-'
```

How would i change my code to fix this?

I think I know that what is happening is what is being printed out is the code in bytes and it needs to be converted to a string, but do I do this on the server or client side of the program?

When i write

```
print(f"receivedquote: {data}".decode('utf-8')
```

that does not do the trick. I get a lot of errors.  How can I ask this question better to find a solution?

Comment: You need to decode just the `data` string not the entire "Received quote: {data}" string.

Answer (score 1):

Decode the actual data:

```
data = data.decode('utf-8')
```

At this point, `data` is a Python Unicode string which you can print, search, slice, etc.

(Your data doesn't particularly look like UTF-8 but I'm not going to second-guess that; it's not clearly not UTF-8, either.)

It's generally a good idea to convert to Unicode immediately after receiving a byte string, and have the rest of your program operate on strings. If you need to encode back to bytes, similarly do that only at the perimeter, jut before the data leaves your program. ([Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) calls this "Unicode sandwiching.")